# Cooking by drowning

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature

Imagine you drop a giant sack full of fish into the sea.
As the sack drowns deeper, the pressure will compress the air inside the sack.
This will make the temperature rise inside the sack.

Is it possible to cook something with this method?

Edit (tldr, don't propose machines):
I am specifically asking about the physics side of things.
e.g. will it be able to reach a high enough temp, sustain it, and cook the fish.
The mechanism is of little concern to me.

Comment: Definitely a What-If candidate

Comment: The answer will depend on whether the sinking is fast enough that the heat transfer is approximately adiabatic. But why does the sack of fish sink at all? Fish tend to neutrally buoyant; air is positively buoyant.

Comment: This question being marked as "about engineering" is hilarious.

Comment: This is physics, and thought-provoking physics too. Please don't give it to the engineers!

Comment: ... indeed, it would be a good exam question, and also as a school teaching exercise it could make a great physics lesson. Could a ship which has to provide many meals save some energy this way?

Comment: Considering the large mass times heat capacity of the fish compared to that of the interstitial air, the temperature rise of the combination will be much much less than that obtained by adiabatically compressing air alone.  I have substituted an analysis of this situation in place of my previous answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Neat question.

You'd really want to run some numerics or solve some equations to be sure, but my guess is this.

The sack isn't isolated from the environment, in the sense that changes in temperature in the environment propagate through the sack. Furthermore, the sack is falling slowly enough that it can be modeled as always at thermal equilibrium with its environment, so the temperature inside the sack is roughly that outside it. It gets colder the further you go.

So my guess is you've found a ridiculous freezer rather than a ridiculous cooker.

Comment: I did try to make a very simple model, but the heat dissipation seemed to be a problem indeed :(

Comment: "Adiabatic" usually means that there is negligible heat flow, which is the opposite of the situation you're describing.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Fair enough... I'm used to quantum where "adiabatic" means "slow." I've edited my answer.

Comment: I suspect the OP is proposing a sack made of a particular type of unobtanium which does not transmit energy.  That's why the contents will heat under compression, rather like the fluid in an air-conditioning compressor.   (tho' an AC system running on fish would probably smell bad)

Comment: Maybe the sack could be replaced with two metal plates joined by a bellows with the fish inside. The container is locked in an expanded position and dropped in the ocean. Upon reaching the deepest, murkiest depths, the lock is released and the bellows collapse, crushing the fish beneath the metal plates. Perhaps this could generate some heat.

Comment: @MarkH Now we're cooking!

Comment: Sinking it in the deep ocean seems cumbersome. Why not just place the fish in one of the combustion chambers of a [big diesel engine](https://www.mes.co.jp/shared/img/page-image04.jpg) (turn off the fuel injectors for that cylinder, of course!) and run the engine until the fish is done?

Comment: Well, best proposal would be to put fish into the container filled with [Triethylborane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triethylborane) which has autoignition temperature of $-20^\circ C$ and let it go into the oceans. Then if you are lucky enough maybe at the very bottom it will ignite and prepare your fish. Be ready to perform anti-toxic procedures after eating ;-D

Comment: I formulated and solved the equations you referred to for the most optimistic case of an adiabatic container.  See my answer below.  It shows that the temperature response of the system is much less than compression of pure air because of the large thermal inertial of the fish (compared to the air).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have a sealed sack of fish. The source of pressure is the weight of water above the sack, which will increase with increasing depth.

I'm imaging a model here. Assuming an adiabatic process resulting in an increase in temperature as in $ T = (P+P_{atm})V/nR$ from the ideal gas equation (with $P_{atm} = 1$ bar or so), the product $(P+P_{atm})V$ will clearly depend on the external pressure / ocean depth. For the sack to remain stable, $P = P_{ext} = \rho gh +P_{atm}$. As $h$ increases, $P$ increases. Given the specific heat capacity of the air inside the sack, we can derive an expression for $V$ in terms of $P$ and $\gamma$. That is, $V = (k/(P+P_{atm}))^{1/\gamma}$.

$ T = (\rho gh+P_{atm})^{(\gamma -1)/\gamma}(k)^{1/\gamma}/nR$

Answer (score 0):

I think you could consider the diesel effect if you design one portion of the chamber to collapse at sufficient pressure. This happens when submarine exceed crush depth as bulkheads collapse.

So if your cooking chamber has one volume with a movable wall as a piston that is exposed to the large amount of sea pressure due to rupturing a diaphragm or some other mechanism. Then you could calculate how hot the new volume of air  in a fairly precise way, and the cooking time would be determine by how well insulated the cooking chamber is with respect to the surrounding sea water.

Answer (score -1):

Considering the large mass times heat capacity of the fish compared to that of the interstitial air, the temperature rise of the combination will be much much less than that obtained by adiabatically compressing air alone.  Here is a detailed analysis of that situation:

Consider that the flexible container is perfect insulation so that the compression takes place adiabatically.  Let $\phi_0$ represent the initial volume fraction of air in the container and let $V_0$ be the initial volume of air and fish.  Then the initial volume of air in the container is $\phi_0V_0$ and the initial volume of fish in the container is $(1-\phi_0)V_0$. In addition, the number of moles of air in the container is $n=\frac{\phi_0P_0V_0}{RT_0}$.

If we apply the first law of thermodynamics to the adiabatic reversible compression of this system, we obtain:  $$dU=\frac{\phi_0P_0V_0}{RT_0}C_{Va}dT+(1-\phi_0)V_0\rho_fC_{f}dT=-PdV_a=-\frac{\phi_0P_0V_0}{RT_0}\frac{RT}{V_a}dV_a$$where $V_a$ is the volume of air in the interstices, $C_{Va}$ is the molar heat capacity at constant volume of the air (=2.5R), $rho_f$ is the density of fish (assumed 1000 kg/m^3 for mostly water), and $C_{f}$ is the mass heat capacity of fish (assumed 4.184 kJ/kg.C for mostly water).  Multiplying the above equation by $\frac{T_0}{\phi_0P_0V_0T}$ yields:$$\left[\frac{C_{Va}}{R}+\frac{(1-\phi_0)T_0\rho_fC_{f}}{\phi_0P_0}\right]\frac{dT}{T}=-\frac{dV_a}{V_a}\tag 1$$From the ideal gas law, It follows that  that:  $$\frac{dV_a}{V_a}=\frac{dT}{T}-\frac{dP}{P}\tag 2$$ If we combine Eqns. 1 and 2, we obtain:  $$\frac{C_{Pa}}{R}\left[1+\frac{(1-\phi_0)RT_0\rho_fC_{f}}{C_{Pa}\phi_0P_0}\right]\frac{dT}{T}=\frac{dP}{P}\tag 3$$From this, it follows that the combined fish-air system temperature response to a pressure change would be the same as that for pure air compression if the heat capacity at constant pressure of the air had been higher by a factor of $\left[1+\frac{(1-\phi_0)RT_0\rho_fC_{f}}{C_{Pa}\phi_0P_0}\right]$.  For an initial void fraction of 0.2, an initial temperature of 293 K, and an initial pressure of 1 bar, this factor comes out to be equal to 15.  So, we have that $$\frac{T}{T_0}=\left(\frac{P}{P_0}\right)^{\frac{\gamma-1}{15\gamma}}=\left(\frac{P}{P_0}\right)^{0.019}$$which is much much less than compression of pure air.

Comment: This can be easily fixed by attaching a large weight to the sack

Comment: Is this true? For arbitrary (read arbitrarily small) amounts of air? I'm not sure.

Comment: Who says the amounts of air are small?  In a typical porous packing, void fractions of 30 % or more are typical.  I would estimate that in a packing of fish, the void fraction could easily be on the order of several percent.  Otherwise, there's nothing to compress.